# What is the equivalent for datatype LONG in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm working with SQL Server and MS Access databases, but in Access I have a column with the datatype `LONG` and when importing into SQL Server, the wizard shows a warning that the source column type is different than the destination one, unfortunately there is no `LONG` datatype in SQL Server, what is its equivalent in SQL Server to avoid the warning?

[image: Wizard warning]

Comment: Quite much a int in sql server is a long in VBA. So in VBA code, you no doubt near EVERY where used a long for a PK id in a row. You can leave that code "as is" and just assume that when you migrate data or create tables in sql server, you use "int" on the sql server side. Over the years, this is about the only issue you have to much worry about in VBA - but if the application started out as access, and then you migreated data to sql server, then all your VBA code will be the same - just that "int" is to be used sql server side to represent the long in VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant to your particular case:

| Access (UI) | Access (SQL/CREATE TABLE) | VBA | SQL Server | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number (Integer) | Short | Integer | smallint | 16 bit |
| Number (Long Integer) | Integer/Long | Long | int | 32 bit |
| Large Number | ? | LongLong | bigint | 64 bit |

Some additional information:

- The reason for this inconsistency is historic. In a nutshell, it boils down to whether you define your standard "integer" type as a 16-bit or as a 32-bit type.
- The value shown as "source type" your screenshot is probably from the second column in my table above. Access itself does not use the word "VarChar" in its user interface.

Sources:

- [Microsoft Access Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Comparing Access and SQL Server data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/comparing-access-and-sql-server-data-types-9188f41d-6c0e-4733-9d20-d08916f50bd2)